# Why is TableCellRenderer null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtable, tablecellrenderer

When my table updates itself with new data, it calls `prepareRenderer`. This is by default what a JTable does when updated. However, when my program calls the prepareRenderer method, it is giving it a null TableCellRenderer in it's arguments. Therefore I get a null pointer exception.

```
    dataTable = new javax.swing.JTable() {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            return super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        }
    };
```

That is how I declare it. The @Override isn't even really needed. I put it there so I can put a breakpoint in it so I could see it was actually firing and what the arguments' values were. For whatever reason, when java called this prepareRender method, it gives a null value for the TableCellRenderer argument. Why is it doing that and how do I fix it? I get nothing on the screen because of the NPE.

Comment: Boy it is annoying that you just posted another question when you have a question on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180429/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-using-jtab. You were asked to post a proper `SSCCE`. Not doing so is just wasting everybodies time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my tablemodel. Specifically, the `getColumnClass` method was not returning anything (null's only) because of how I was coding the return. If the getColumnClass method does not work, the tablecellrender fails because it doesn't know how to show the data.

Comment: Post a proper `SSCCE` when you ask a question. There is absolutely no way we could guess what your problem was based on the vague description of the problem and 2 lines of code. You continue to waste peoples time.